# solution to $\square\chi=f$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, electromagnetism

For an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$, if $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ is a "good" (for example, smooth) function, is there a solution to the following equation?

$$\left( \Delta - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\chi(x, y, z, t)=f(x, y, z, t)$$

**Context**

I want to transform Maxwell's equations

$$\operatorname{rot}E(x,t)+\frac{\partial B(x, t)}{\partial t}=0$$
$$\operatorname{div}B(x,t)=0$$
$$\operatorname{rot}H(x,t)-\frac{\partial D(x,t)}{\partial t}=i(x,t)$$
$$\operatorname{div}D(x,t)=\rho(x,t)$$

into the following form with the electrical potential $\phi$ and the vector potential $A$:

$$B(x,t)=\operatorname{rot}A_L(x,t)$$
$$E(x,t)=-\frac{\partial A_L(x,t)}{\partial t} -\operatorname{grad}\phi_L(x,t)$$
$$\square A_L(x,t)=-\mu_0i(x,t)$$
$$\square \phi_L(x,t) = -\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\rho(x,t)$$
$$\operatorname{div}A_L(x, t)+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial\phi_L(x,t)}{\partial t}=0$$

In order to do this, we need the existence of a solution to the equation

$$\square\chi = -\left(\operatorname{div}A_0 + \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \phi_0}{\partial t}\right)$$

where $A_0$ and $\phi_0$ is a special solution to the following equations:

$$B(x,t)=\operatorname{rot}A(x,t)$$
$$E(x,t)=-\frac{\partial A(x,t)}{\partial t} -\operatorname{grad}\phi(x,t)$$
$$\operatorname{grad}\left( \operatorname{div}A(x,t)+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial t}\right) + \left( \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\Delta\right)A(x,t)=\mu_0 i(x,t)$$
$$-\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\partial A(x,t)}{\partial t}\right) - \Delta \phi(x,t)=\frac{\rho(x,t)}{\epsilon_0}$$

If it exists, $A_L$ and $\phi_L$ are defined as follows:

$$A_L = A_0 + \operatorname{grad}\chi$$
$$\phi_L = \phi_0 - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\chi$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question if whether a solution $\chi$ to the the following equation exists
$$
-\frac{1}{c^{2}}\square=\left(\Delta - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\chi=f\;\text{ in }\;\Bbb R^4\equiv \Bbb R^3\times \Bbb R \label{w}\tag{W}
$$ 
under mild smoothness requirements on the datum $f$ is **yes**: I explain below why it is so in a *constructive way*, by actually constructing an explicit solution in two steps:

1. **Construction of a fundamental solution**: what is needed is a slightly modified *fundamental solution* of the D'Alembert operator, precisely the solution of the following equation:
   $$
   \square \mathscr{E}(x,t)=-c^2\delta(x,t)\label{da}\tag{DA}
   $$
   where $\delta(x,t)\equiv \delta(x)\times\delta(t)$ is the usual *tensor product* of Dirac measures respectively on the *spatial and on the time domain*. Once  $\mathscr{E}(x,t)$ has been determined, we can find, provided certain compatiility conditions on $f$ are fulfilled (see below), a *distributional solution $\chi(x,t)$* to the posed problem by convolution
   $$
   \chi(x,t)=\mathscr{E}\ast f(x,t)\label{s}\tag{S}
   $$
   The minimal requirements on $f$ is that *the convolution product at the right term of \eqref{s} should exists as a distribution*.
2. **The regularity problem**: prove that, provided $f$ is a "good" (for example $C^2$ smooth) function, the distribution $\chi$ in \eqref{s} is a "good" function in the same way.

> **Calculation of the modified fundamental solution for the D'Alembert operator in $\Bbb R^{3+1}$**

We construct $\mathscr{E}$ as a *distribution of slow growth* (i.e. $\mathscr{E}\in \mathscr{S}^\prime$, see for example [1] §8.1-§8.2, pp. 113-116 or [2], §5.1-§5.2, pp. 74-78) by applying to PDE \eqref{da} the Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}_{x\to\xi}$ respect to the spatial variable $x$. By proceeding this way, \eqref{da} is transformed into the following ODE:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \hat{\mathscr{E}}(\xi,t)}{\partial t^2} + c^2|\xi|^2\hat{\mathscr{E}}(\xi,t)=-c^2\delta(t)\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Consider its equivalent *standard form* 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \hat{\mathscr{E}}_p(\xi,t)}{\partial t^2} + c^2|\xi|^2\hat{\mathscr{E}}_p(\xi,t)=\delta(t)\label{1'}\tag{1'}
$$
which has the same solutions, just multiplied by the constant $-c^2$: by solving it (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021903/particular-solution-of-second-order-differential-equation/3023229#3023229), [1] §10.5, p. 147 or [2], §4.9, example 4.9.6 pp. 77-74 and §15.4, example 15.4.4) we get the following distribution
$$
\hat{\mathscr{E}}_p(\xi,t)= H(t)\frac{\sin c|\xi|t}{c|\xi|}\iff\hat{\mathscr{E}}(\xi,t)= -cH(t)\frac{\sin c|\xi|t}{|\xi|}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
where $H(t)$ is the usual *Heaviside function*. Then, taking the inverse Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}_{\xi\to x}^{-1}\big(\hat{\mathscr{E}}\big)$ we get the sought for solution of \eqref{da} (see [1] §9.8, p. 135 and §10.7, p. 149)
$$
\mathscr{E}(x,t)=-\frac{H(t)}{4\pi t}\delta_{S_{ct}}(x)=-c\frac{H(t)}{2\pi }\delta\big(c^2t^2-|x|^2\big)\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
where

- $S_{ct}=\{x\in\Bbb R^3 | |x|^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=c^2t^2\}$ is the *spherical light wave surface*,
- $\delta_{S_{ct}}(x)$ is the Dirac measure supported on $S_{ct}$, otherwise called *single layer measure*.

Now, given any distribution $f\in\mathscr{D}(\Bbb R^{3+1})$ for which the convolution with $\mathscr{E}$ exists (for example *any distribution of compact support*) using \eqref{3} in formula \eqref{s} gives a generalized solution of \eqref{w}.

> **Construction of a regular solution**

Instead of recurring to the standard (and complex) methods of regularity theory we will try a trickier way by looking carefully at the structure of \eqref{3} and on how this distribution acts on the space of infinitely smooth rapidly decreasing functions: precisely, given $\varphi\in\mathscr{S}$ we have that
$$
\begin{split}
\langle\mathscr{E},\varphi\rangle&=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\langle\delta_{S_{ct}},\varphi\rangle\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int\limits_{S_{ct}}\varphi(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma_x\mathrm{d}t
\end{split}\label{4}\tag{4}
$$
From \eqref{4} we see that $\mathscr{E}$ acts on $\varphi\in\mathscr{S}$ as a spherical mean respect to the spatial $x\in \Bbb R^3$ variable and as a weighted time integral mean with weight function $t\mapsto {1\over t}\in L^1_\mathrm{loc}$  respect to the time variable $t\in\Bbb R_+$.
This implies that \eqref{4} is meaningful also for functions which are not in $\mathscr{S}$ nor are infinitely smooth. Precisely, provided that

- $\varphi(\cdot,t)\in L^1_\mathrm{loc}(\Bbb R^3)$ for almost all $t\in\Bbb R_+$, *without any growth condition at infinity* and
- $\varphi(x,\cdot)\in L^1_\mathrm{loc}(\Bbb R)$ with $|\varphi(x,t)|=O(t^{-\varepsilon})$ as $t\to\infty$ a.e. on $\Bbb R^3$ with $0<c\le\varepsilon$.

equation \eqref{4} is meaningful. Then, by putting 
$$
\varphi(y,\tau)=f(x-y,t-\tau)
$$
and by using \eqref{4} jointly with the definition of convolution between a distribution and a function, i.e.
$$
\mathscr{E}\ast\varphi (x,t) \triangleq \langle \mathscr{E}, \varphi(x-y,t-\tau)\rangle
$$
we get the sought for solution
$$
\chi(x,t)=\mathscr{E}\ast f(x,t)=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\tau}\int\limits_{S_{c\tau}}f(x-y,t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma_y\mathrm{d}\tau
\label{S}\tag{WS}
$$

**Notes**

- The hypothesis $n=3$, i.e. the fact that we are working in a $3$D space, is essential for defining the structure of \eqref{3}. The inverse transform of $\hat{\mathscr{E}}$ in \eqref{2} *has not the same structure on every $\Bbb R^n$*: in monographs on hyperbolic PDEs, this concept is also stated by saying that *Huygens's principle does not hold in even spatial dimension*.
- The regularity of the solution we have obtained is very weak: in particularly *we do not know the smoothness of $\chi$ for a given smoothness of $f$*. Deeper methods are required for the investigation of this problems.

[1] V. S. Vladimirov (1971)[1967], [*Equations of mathematical physics*](https://books.google.it/books?id=2f9uDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false), Translated from the Russian original (1967) by Audrey Littlewood. Edited by Alan Jeffrey, (English), Pure and Applied Mathematics, Vol. 3, New York: Marcel Dekker, Inc., pp. vi+418, [MR0268497](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0268497), [Zbl 0207.09101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0207.09101).

[2] V. S. Vladimirov (2002), *[Methods of the theory of generalized functions](https://books.google.it/books?id=6UpZDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it)*, Analytical Methods and Special Functions, Vol. 6, London–New York: Taylor & Francis, pp. XII+353, ISBN 0-415-27356-0, [MR2012831](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR2012831), [Zbl 1078.46029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1078.46029).