# Laplace and Fourier Transforms to derive an Unsteady Fundamental Solution

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I am considering the equations for unsteady Stokes flow

$$
\left\{
\begin{split}
\nabla \cdot u &= 0,\\
\\
\rho \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= -\nabla p + \mu \nabla^2 u.\\
\end{split}
\right.
$$

In a paper (which I can provide if necessary) it is stated that one can use Fourier and Laplace transforms on these equations to obtain the unsteady fundamental solution.

I have not used a lot of transform theory before so was wondering how this would work, does one separate the variables out to have an ODE in the time variable which is solved with the Laplace transform and the Fourier transform is kept for the spatial part?

Edit: Obviously one does not transform these equations directly to get the fundamental solution, but these equations with the appropriate singular point forcing.

Comment: Hi Tom, can you provide the bibliographical reference for the paper? I'd like to have a look at it.

Comment: Hi Daniele, yes I can link to the paper here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0955799706000956

Comment: So I guess my question is do you do some sort of separation, or do you hit all the equations with the Fourier transform followed by the Laplace transform (or other way around), then solve the algebraic equations and reverse with the inverse Fourier transform followed by the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: The basic procedure in this case seems to be the one you detailed: however, while in the [standard cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064926/solution-to-square-chi-f/3079988#3079988) (where you can also avoid the use of Laplace transform) the procedure is straightforward, for the Stokes system the condition $\operatorname{div} u=0$ make the related algebraic system overdetermined, thus we need to be more careful: I asked you the paper reference in order to see if there is something I am overlooking.

Comment: Hi Daniele, in my comment above I provide a link to the paper, is this not what you meant?  I believe the Laplace transform is probably used to keep the analysis in real variables.

Comment: I believe there is also more information in a paper entitled 'Unsteady Stokes flow in two dimensions' by SH Smith, the original paper I was referring to is 'MFS with time-dependent fundamental solutions for unsteady Stokes equations' by Tsai et al.

Comment: Tom, the link you provided is very useful and clarifying. For the sake of completeness I will have a look at the paper of Smith and write down an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Daniele, unfortunately the reward I put on the question has expired but I would still appreciate it if you are able to come up with an answer.

Comment: I’ll do it . Ad sono ad possibile.

Comment: Tom, I did it. I delayed the answer for two reasons: lack of time, and difficulty in finding some meaningful sources to add. However here it is and I hope you enjoy it.

Comment: Hi Daniele, this is really helpful, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Tom, you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More a long comment that a full answer.
 
In some sense your guess is correct, since this is exactly how these transforms are used when they are applied jointly to a PDE: in the first explicit reference I recall, Richard Briggs explicitly says that in his monograph he will "*perform Laplace transformation with respect to time and a Fourier transformation with respect to the spatial coordinate ...*" ([1], §2,2 p. 12).
However, *the reason for performing Laplace transform respect to the time variable for systems of PDEs is subtler respect to the need to solve an (at most second order, in most cases) ordinary differential equation*. Indeed, as shown in this [Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064926/solution-to-square-chi-f/3079988#3079988) (already cited in comments), if you have a single PDE you can simply apply to it the Fourier transform respect to the spatial variable and solve the resulting ODE by *any elementary methods*. Now let's consider what  happens if you have the following system of first order respect to time PDEs:
$$
\partial_t\mathbf u= \mathbf A(\partial_\mathbf{x})\mathbf{u}\label{ex}\tag{Ex.}
$$
where

- $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$, $n\ge 2$ is the unknown $n$-dimensional vector,
- $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$, $m\ge 1$ is the $m$-dimensional spatial variable $\implies\partial_\mathbf{x}=(\partial_{x_1},\ldots,\partial_{x_m})$ is the $m$-dimensional vector of the partial derivatives respect to the components of $\mathbf{x}$,
- $\mathbf A(\partial_\mathbf{x})$ is a $n\times n$ matrix partial differential operator whose entries are polynomial in the variables $\partial_\mathbf{x}$ with complex coefficients.

If you apply to \eqref{ex} the Fourier transform respect to $\mathbf{x}$ i.e. $\mathscr{F}_{\bf{x}\mapsto\boldsymbol{\xi}}$ you get the following *system of ODEs*
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf u}{\mathrm{d}t}= \mathbf A(2\pi i\boldsymbol{\xi})\mathbf{u}\label{e}\tag{Ex.}
$$
which is easily (almost from the theoretic point of view) solvable by calculating its *fundamental matrix* 
$$
e^{t\mathbf{A}(2\pi i\boldsymbol{\xi})}\label{fs}\tag{FS}
$$ 
by putting
$$
\mathbf{u}=e^{t\mathbf{A}(2\pi i\boldsymbol{\xi})}\mathbf{u}_0
$$
where $\mathbf{u}_0$ is the initial condition for the system \eqref{ex}. However, as Peter Henrici notes is his monumental work [2] §12.5, p. 537 example 7, calculating \eqref{fs} is not an easy task and also can hidden the structure of the solution respect to the spatial variables. Therefore, when dealing with systems of PDEs **it is strongly advisable too algebrize completely the problem**, i.e. to transform the problem at and in the linear algebra problem of solving possibly determined homogeneous or not, system of linear equations.

In our case, the 3D Stokes system, assuming the notation of [3], pp. 898-899, and putting $\mathbf u=(u,v,w)$, $\mathbf x=(x,y,z)$,  $\boldsymbol\xi=(\xi_1, \xi_2,\xi_3)$, we have
$$
\left\{
\begin{split}
0 &= \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial{w}}{\partial z}\\
\rho \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= -\frac{\partial{p}}{\partial x} + \mu \nabla^2 u + \alpha_1\delta(\mathbf x)\delta(t)\\
\rho \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} &= -\frac{\partial{p}}{\partial y} + \mu \nabla^2 v + \alpha_2\delta(\mathbf x)\delta(t)\\
\rho \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial t} &= -\frac{\partial{p}}{\partial z} + \mu \nabla^2 w + \alpha_3\delta(\mathbf x)\delta(t)\\
\end{split}
\right.\label{st}\tag{ST}
$$
Obviously, since we are dealing with fundamental solutions, we should work in the framework of generalized function, for example distributions: thus we assume that $p, u,v,w$ belong to the space of Schwartz distributions $\mathscr{S}^\prime(\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R)$, in order to be able to do Fourier analysis.

Applying Laplace transformation $\mathscr{L}_{t\mapsto s}$ we first get
$$
\left\{
\begin{split}
0 &= \frac{\partial\hat{u}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial\hat{v}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial\hat{w}}{\partial z}\\
\rho s \hat{u} &= -\frac{\partial\hat{p}}{\partial x} + \mu \nabla^2 \hat{u} + \alpha_1\delta(\mathbf x)\\
\rho s \hat{v} &= -\frac{\partial\hat{p}}{\partial y} + \mu \nabla^2 \hat{v} + \alpha_2\delta(\mathbf x)\\
\rho s \hat{w} &= -\frac{\partial\hat{p}}{\partial z} + \mu \nabla^2 \hat{w} + \alpha_3\delta(\mathbf x)\\
\end{split}
\right.,
$$
and then applying the Fourier transform respect to the $\bf{x}$ variable $\mathscr{F}_{\bf{x}\mapsto\boldsymbol{\xi}}$
$$
\left\{
\begin{split}
0 &= \xi_1\hat{u} + \xi_2\hat{v} + \xi_3\hat{w}\\
\rho s \hat{u} &= -2\pi i\xi_1\hat{p} - 4 \mu \pi^2 \Vert\boldsymbol\xi\Vert^2 \hat{u} + \alpha_1\\
\rho s \hat{v} &= -2\pi i\xi_2\hat{p} - 4 \mu \pi^2 \Vert\boldsymbol\xi\Vert^2 \hat{v} + \alpha_2\\
\rho s \hat{w} &= -2\pi i\xi_3\hat{p} - 4 \mu \pi^2 \Vert\boldsymbol\xi\Vert^2 \hat{w} + \alpha_3\\
\end{split}
\right..
$$
(by abuse of notation but for simplicity reasons, we do not change the symbols $ \hat{p}, \hat{u}, \hat{v}, \hat{w}$) and thus we finally get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\xi_1 &  \xi_2 &  \xi_3 & 0 \\
(\rho s + 4 \mu \pi^2 \Vert\boldsymbol\xi\Vert^2) & 0 & 0 & 2\pi i\xi_1 \\
0 & (\rho s + 4 \mu \pi^2 \Vert\boldsymbol\xi\Vert^2) & 0 & 2\pi i\xi_2 \\
0 & 0 & (\rho s + 4 \mu \pi^2 \Vert\boldsymbol\xi\Vert^2) & 2\pi i\xi_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{u}\\
\hat{v}\\
\hat{w}\\
\hat{p}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
\alpha_1\\
\alpha_2\\
\alpha_3\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now we have a fully algebraic, nonhomogeneous determined linear system which is solvable by elementary means. The solution vector we obtain is the Laplace transform respect to time and the Fourier transform respect to the spatial variable of the fundamental solution of the Stokes system \eqref{st}: and in order to reconstruct the fundamental solution, we shall simply component-wise inverse transform the found algebraic expressions with the aid of tables which, even if it is not the easiest task around, it is nevertheless less daunting that calculating first \eqref{fs} and then its inverse Fourier transform.

**References**

[1] Richard J. Briggs, *Electron-stream Interaction with Plasmas*, M.I.T. Press research monographs 29, Cambridge, Mass.: M.I.T. Press, pp. 187 (1964).

[2] Henrici, Peter, *Applied and computational complex analysis. Vol. 2: Special functions-integral transforms-asymptotics-continued fractions*, Wiley Classics Library. New York: Wiley. ix, 662 p. (1991). [ZBL0925.30003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0925.30003).

[3] Tsai, C. C.; Young, D. L.; Fan, C. M.; Chen, C. W., "[MFS with time-dependent fundamental solutions for unsteady Stokes equations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.enganabound.2006.04.006)", Engineering Analysis with Boundary Elements 30, No. 10, 897-908 (2006). [ZBL1195.76324](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1195.76324).

Comment: I have one other question which I don't think is obvious from [3]: what does the unsteady Stokeslet actually look like ie. can it be written down explicitly in vector form?

Comment: @Tom, sure: look at formula (9) of [3]. You have that the unknown vector fundamental solution $\{u^\ast, v^\ast, w^\ast, p^\ast\}$ of \eqref{st} is expressed as the matrix product of the matrix $(B_{ij})_{i, j =1,\ldots,n}$, whose entries $B_{ij}$ are known functions of $x, y, z$ and $t$ (remember that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$), by the constant vector $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3\}$. By explicitly doing each row-by-column multiplication, you get the component wise expression of the fundamental solution of \eqref{st}.

Comment: @Tom, probably the authors of [3] prefer to keep the form (9) since it is easier to express other quantities involved by using it instead of the standard, vector form: think for example to the expression (11) of the vorticity $\{\omega^\ast_x, \omega^\ast_y, \omega^\ast_z\}$, which is kept in the same form.

Comment: But would it just be trivial I suppose to deconstruct it down into the vector form?

Comment: @Tom, yes it would be trivial.

Comment: Hi Daniele, I tried solving the linear system for the 2D case the other day and the result was rather complicated, for example for $\hat{u}_1$ one seems to get $k_2 \alpha_1 (k_1 - k_2)/(4 \mu \pi^2 k_1^3k_2 - 4 \mu \pi^2 k_1^2 k_2^2 + 4 \mu \pi^2 k_1 k_2^3 - 4 \mu \pi^2 k_2^4 - k_1^2 \rho s - k_2^2 \rho s)$, is this really invertible using inverse transforms from tables?

Comment: I am not sure if this answer is even correct as I obtained it putting it into Maple and not sure that I trust Maple.

Comment: Hi @Tom: I am not sure if your expression is correct, and also I am not sure if Maple could be trusted or not for the solution of a $3\times 3$ linear algebraic system. However, the result you got looks correct to me: and as you see, the vector representation of the fundamental solutions looks quite complex already in the Fourier-Laplace domain, and this convinces me more and more of the truth of the observation I made at the end of my answer: they keep it in matrix form in order to compute less than $3\times 3$ simpler antitransformations instead of $3$ complex ones.

Comment: I also had a quick look at the text of Banerjee cited as a references by the Authors of [3] and I saw that, despite having the entire appendix A devoted to the calculus of fundamental solutions, the determination of Stokeslets seems not explicitly done. However I have not checked the whole text, therefore I may have been missing something.