# find a function $f(t)$ such that $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}(s)=f(s)/s$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, laplace-transform

find a function $f(t)$ such that $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}(s)=f(s)/s$

Does such a function $f(t)$ exist?

This came up while I was playing around with p-adic Norms.

Comment: Any constant function will satisfy this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in almost any book on the Laplace transform, we have that
$$
\mathscr{L}\left[\int\limits_0^t f(r)\mathrm{d}r\right](s)=\frac{F(s)}{s} + \frac{1}{s} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} f(r)\mathrm{d}r \iff \frac{F(s)}{s} = \mathscr{L}\left[\int\limits_0^t f(r)\mathrm{d}r\right](s) - \frac{1}{s} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} f(r)\mathrm{d}r
$$
and then using the fact that in this case you have $F(s)= f(s)$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
f(t)& =\mathscr{L}^{-1}\big[\mathscr{L}[f(t)](s)\big](t)\\
& = \mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\mathscr{L}\left[\int\limits_0^t f(r)\mathrm{d}r\right](s) - \frac{1}{s} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} f(r)\mathrm{d}r\right](t)\\
& = \int\limits_0^t f(r)\mathrm{d}r - H(t)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} f(r)\mathrm{d}r
\end{split}
$$
where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside function. Thus you have an integral equation which can be reduced by differentiation to the following first order linear ordinary differential equation:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}f(t)= f(t) - \delta (t)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} f(r)\mathrm{d}r\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta distribution.

**Solution to equation \eqref{1}**.

First note that \eqref{1} *is linear* since
$$
c_\infty=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} f(r)\mathrm{d}r\label{ic}\tag{IC}.
$$
should be considered as a datum. Said that, we start seeking the solution of \eqref{1} in the form $f(t)= f_o(t) + f_p(t)$, where $f_p(t)$ is a particular solution found as described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021903/particular-solution-of-second-order-differential-equation/3023229#3023229) and $f_o(t)$ is the solution of the associated homogeneous equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}f_o(t)= f_o(t).\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
We have
$$
\begin{split}
f_o(t) &=c e^t\\
f_p(t) &=c_\infty H(t)e^t
\end{split}
$$
where $c$ is a constant to be determined: and in order to determine it, we use the integral condition \eqref{ic}, obtaining
$$
c_\infty = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} f(r)\mathrm{d}r = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} f_o(r)\mathrm{d}r =c \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} e^r\mathrm{d}r = c\big[e^t\big]_{-\infty}^{0+} = c
$$
Finally,
$$
f(t)= c_\infty e^t\big[1+H(t)\big]
$$

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed explanation. I am unsure how to solve the first order linear ordinary differential equation.

Comment: Thank you @pj5772: first of all, you have to consider the quantity $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0^+} f(t)\mathrm{d}t$$ as a datum. Then you have to calculate the fundamental solution of the linear ODE in the standard way as shown, for example, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021903/particular-solution-of-second-order-differential-equation/3023229#3023229). However, if you need some more help, I'll work the solution this evening, after work.